# Are there efficient methods of black box testing that can avoid redundancy?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, redundancy, black-box-testing

I've been conducting black box testing for a software program that does engineering analysis on different types of concentrated solar power (CSP) models.

The quality assurance testing I've been conducting has involved only changing one default parameters of the model at a time. It's been very simple where I've just been verifying whether or not the output matches the expected result.

However, now I want to start exploring combinations of configurations that differ from the default set up to investigate if any of these combinations will output an incorrect value or even cause the user interface (UI) to fail.

The first instance I am working with, the UI has (6) different types of parameters I am expected to explore with respect to the default configuration. On top of this, I want to explore combinations of the (6) configuration options by varying them by either increasing (+) or decreasing (-) them, with respect to the default configuration.

As you can imagine, by wanting to explore these (6) parameters in combinations of (+) & (-), I'll easily create many MANY different types of black box tests.

Is there any suggestions on how to conduct these black box tests in a more efficient way? I am trying to avoid conducting all different types of configurations while still exploring the computing code in all aspects.

Comment: How can you *explore the computing code in all aspects* without conducting all different types of configurations? Seems like you're asking for testing, say, a compiler without giving it all sorts of programs. IMHO, you should use a RNG to generate the input configurations.

Comment: That is the real issue I'm trying to work around. I am just not sure if it is a realistic want for this problem. I was initially exploring factorial designs ... I dont want to get into details but since there are (6) factors, varied in (3) different ways (+, -, and the default setting) for each parameter, I'm essentially looking at a unit test scenario testing 3^6 configurations. I don't think factorial designs are the answer though. Can you please specify on what you mean with RNG?

Comment: I was thinking about continuous rather than discrete input as in your case (that was not clear from the original question). RNG = random number generator. Well you should test all 3^6=729 configurations -- it's not many after all.

Comment: @Walter, as a beginner programmer in C++, I cannot tell if you are serious or not on whether 729 unit tests is a reasonable amount of testing to be done ... manually. For reference, I'm using Google Test Framework. Prior before this endeavor, when I was changing a single parameter with respect to the default configuration, it provided a decent amount of manual input on my end.

Comment: If you really need full coverage of all parameter combinations, I would suggest it's reasonable to write a small program in _any_ language you are comfortable with, which generates the code for these unit tests.

Comment: Are you testing the whole program, or are you testing small pieces of code, like, single functions or methods?  In the first case, you are not doing unit-testing.

Comment: It turns out the solution for my answer is called 'combinatorial testing'. This is essentially still a black-box method of unit testing where it cuts down on the number of total unit tests while still capturing the entire spectrum of parameters under inspection. The cool thing about combinatorial testing, is that it's specifically used for software QA where it helps the user detect obscure software faults through the interactions of parameter combinations, just without requiring the user to complete an *exhaustive testing* scenario.